# Passing variable from one function to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass the variable 'styles' down to the the style = {styles}. How might I go about doing this?

```
function Header() {
    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    var currentScrollpos = window.pageYOffset
    window.onscroll = function () {
        if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollpos){
            var styles = {
                top: '0'
            }
        } else {
            var styles = {
                top: '-100px'
            }
        }
    }


    return (
        <div className = 'navbar' style = {styles}>
            <div id = 'mainButtons' >
                    <button id = 'projects'> PROJECTS </button>
                    <button id = 'about'> ABOUT </button>
                    <button id = 'contact'> CONTACT </button>
                    <button id = 'resume'> RESUME </button>

            </div>
        </div>
         )
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are working with functional components, you could try using [React Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) and store it as part of your component's [State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). Do note that react hooks are only added on React 16.8.

```
function Header() {
  const [headerStyle, setHeaderStyle] = useState({
    top: '0',
  });

  window.onscroll = function () {
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollpos){
      setHeaderStyle({
        top: '0',
      });
     } else {
       setHeaderStyle({
         top: '-100px',
       });
      }
  }

  return (
    <div className = 'navbar' style = {styles}>
      <div id = 'mainButtons' >
        <button id = 'projects'> PROJECTS </button>
        <button id = 'about'> ABOUT </button>
        <button id = 'contact'> CONTACT </button>
        <button id = 'resume'> RESUME </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )


}
```

Comment: Adding to this, could also do `setHeaderStyle({ top: prevScrollpos > currentScrollpos ? '0' : '-100px' })

Comment: @DevonNorris superb :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to use state(which you should not if something can be rather passed as props), you could do this

```
function Header() {
    const styles = {};
    const updateStyle = top => {
        styles.top = top;
    };

window.onscroll = function() {
    if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollpos) {
        updateStyle(0);
    } else {
        updateStyle(-100);
    }
};

return (
    <div className="navbar" style={styles}>
        <div id="mainButtons">
            <button id="projects"> PROJECTS </button>
            <button id="about"> ABOUT </button>
            <button id="contact"> CONTACT </button>
            <button id="resume"> RESUME </button>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

}